# How to adjust navigation design for different browsers?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am a noob when it comes to web design. I downloaded a template to create a site with but My navigation bar looks great in Chrome but is not positioned correctly in FireFox and a part of it is not positioned correctly in IE. Below is my code. I am not sure if this template was like this at the start or after I started adjusting it. I only used chrome for previews when I first started this.

HTML

```
<nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li class="alpha" id="menu_active"><a href="index.html"><span><span>Home</span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="Whatisllf.html"><span><span>What is LLF?</span></span> </a></li>
                <li><a href="TeamManagement.html"><span><span>Team Management</span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="PlayerData.html"><span><span>Player Data</span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="PostSeason.html"><span><span>Post Season</span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="Forums.html"><span><span>Forums</span></span></a></li>
                <li class="omega"><a href="PrivacyPolicy.html"><span><span>Privacy Policy</span></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
#menu {width:100%;overflow:hidden;margin-top:3px}
#menu li {float: left;}
#menu a {display:block;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;color:#000;background:url(../images/menu.gif) top repeat-x;line-height:55px;text-decoration:none}
#menu li span {display:block;background:url(../images/menu_left.gif) top left no-repeat}
#menu .alpha span {background:url(../images/left_menu.gif) top left no-repeat}
#menu .alpha a:hover span,#menu .alpha#menu_active a span {background:url(../images/left_menu_active.gif) top left no-repeat}
#menu .omega span span {background:url(../images/right_menu.gif) top right no-repeat}
#menu .omega a:hover span span,#menu .omega#menu_active a span span {background:url(../images/right_menu_active.gif) top right no-repeat}
#menu li span span,#menu .alpha span span {background:url(../images/menu_right.gif) top right no-repeat;padding:0 24px}
#menu a:hover,#menu #menu_active a {color:#fff;background:url(../images/menu_active.gif) top repeat-x}
#menu a:hover span,#menu #menu_active a span {background:url(../images/menu_left_active.gif) top left no-repeat}
#menu a:hover span span,#menu #menu_active a span span,#menu .alpha#menu_active a span span,#menu .alpha a:hover span span {background:url(../images/menu_right_active.gif) tp right no-repeat}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Conditional CSS](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) .

Comment: ok, Now I see that works for IE but not for firefox...what do I do about Firefox?

Comment: I am not sure if you can use CSS for all the browser types. You may need to use javascript for this. Take a look at [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)